# How can i concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

Using `MySQL`, I can do something like:

```
SELECT c.id_category, c.id_category_type, c.label, c.id_parent
FROM category c
WHERE  c.id_category_type < 3 
ORDER BY c.id_category_type;
```

The result is:

```
id_category |id_category_type |label                 |id_parent |
------------|-----------------|----------------------|----------|
1           |1                |Demande d'information |-1        |
2           |1                |Réclamation           |-1        |
18          |1                |TEST                  |-1        |
3           |2                |Autre                 |1         |
4           |2                |Mairie                |1         |
5           |2                |Stationnement         |1         |
6           |2                |Autre                 |2         |
7           |2                |Familles              |2         |
19          |2                |TESTDOMAINE           |18        |
```

but instead I just want `concat` row who i have a `id_category` with `id_parent`

***Example:***

```
Autre-Demande d'information
Mairie-Demande d'information
Stationnement-Demande d'information
Autre-Réclamation
Familles-Réclamation
TESTDOMAINE-TEST
```

I've looked for a function on [MySQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) and it doesn't look like the `CONCAT` or `CONCAT_WS` functions accept result sets, so does anyone here know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test this:

```
SELECT category.id_category, category.id_category_type, 
CONCAT(category.label, '-', parents.label), category.id_parent  FROM category INNER JOIN
(SELECT id_category AS id, label FROM category WHERE id_parent = -1) AS parents
ON parents.id = category.id_parent WHERE  category.id_category_type < 3 
ORDER BY category.id_category_type;
```

Your data mixes "parents rows" and "child rows": when a register has id_parent = -1, then i consider is a parent row, and when id_parent <> -1 is child row.

You are requesting a result column joining "label" column from "childs rows" and "parents rows", then its necesary build a "parent table", that is achieved with this:

```
(SELECT id_category AS id, label FROM category WHERE id_parent = -1) AS parent
```

then you can use "parent" table like any other table and build your join query